# Inferences about convergence based on two pieces of data

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am new to calculus and just wanted to check my reasoning:

$\sum a_n$ is positive and converges.

This means that:

1. $\sum (-1)^na_n$ also converges, because it converges absolutely.
2. $\sum(sin(n)-2cos(n))·a_n$ converges, because $sin(n)-2cos(n)$ fluctuates between +2.23607 and -2.23607, therefore functioning much like a constant that could be moved to the right of the sum sign.
3. $\sum a_n x^n$ converges if and only if $-1\leq x \leq 1$
4. $\sum a_n^2$ converges, because the data given implies that $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$: therefore $a_n<1$ and $a^2_n<a_n$
5. $a_n$ is a decreasing series (at least starting from some point), again because the data given implies that $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Are each of these conclusions correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First one is true.

2) Second one also, even though the more convenient way to do the majoration is to write
$$|(\sin(n)-2\cos(n))a_n| \leq 3a_n$$

3) This one is not true. For example, let's take $a_n = \frac{1}{3^n}$. Then $\sum a_n x^n$ converges for $x=2$.

4) This is true.

5) This, I don't understand. The sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $0$, but you can say nothing about its monotony. And the series $\sum a_n$ is increasing, because all the $a_n$ are positive.

Comment: Thank you! So if I scrap the word "monotonous", would it be correct to say that $a_n$ (not the sum) will decrease from a certain point and onwards?

Comment: No, it's not because a positive sequence tends to $0$ that it is decreasing (even from a certain point).

Comment: Ok, that means I am lost on this one… Could you give a counter-example? I mean, all the examples I can think of that match the description, e.g. $1/n^2$, do decrease...

Comment: Consider first the sequence $a_n = 1/n$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is even. This sequence is non-negative, tends to $0$, and is not decreasing, even from a certain point. If you want moreover $a_n$ to be non-zero, and $\sum a_n$ to be convergent, consider for example $a_n = 1/n^2$ is $n$ is even and $a_n = 1/(2n^2)$ is $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Number 5 is wrong, consider $a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n^2} \text{ if $n$ is even}\\ \frac{1}{n^3} \text{ if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$